# SharePoint Online List Calculated Field HTML Tags is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, html, calculated-column-formula

in SharePoint migration process we found a list having two calculcated fields.
1. Color: using if condition based on field values, field will get/Set the color.
2. Display: will display the Title value with some color(getting from color field)

Color Field formula, and its working fine.

```
=IF([Status]="DEL","Mag",IF([Status]="PEN","Mag",IF([Status]="SENT","Mag",IF([Status]="WITHD","Gray",IF([Category]="","Blue",IF([Category]="Maint","Blue",IF([Category]="Plan","Blue",IF([Category]="Forced","Darkorange",""))))))))
```

Actual issue is here.
Display Field: formula

```
="<span style='width:100%;display:inline-block;text-align:center;border:1px solid "&Colour&";color:"&Colour&";cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;'>"&Title&"</span>"
```

formula its just getting color field value and style for Title field value.
if i use above formula Title value is displaying but HTML tags also displaying before and after.
just added span tag with title then i understand its issue with HTML or SPO not supporting

ok, MS has stopped this feature here.
But how to solve this issue using **column formatting** in the column settings page.

kindly help me with complete steps, with code also.

Appreciate your help 
[image]

First of all i need to get Title field value, using below code i can get.

```
{ "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json", "elmType": "div", "txtContent": "[$Title]" }
```

i need to apply if condition to set color
Color formula

> =IF([Status]="DECLINED","Magenta",IF([Status]="PENDING","Magenta",IF([Status]="SENT","Magenta",IF([Status]="WITHDRAWN","Gray",IF([Category]="","Blue",IF([Category]="Maintenance","Blue",IF([Category]="Planned","Blue",IF([Category]="Forced","Darkorange",""))))))))

can you help me using above html code how to convert in to JSON, then we need to set style?

Answer (score 0):

Save your calculated column type as "Number" column. It will get rendered if the formula is correct.

**Note: This will only work in CLASSIC MODE as mentioned [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields-a3db28e4-747c-437e-b085-8f795b722a8c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).**

If you are using your site in Modern SharePoint mode, then HTML formatting in SharePoint column is not available in SharePoint Online. Alternatively, you should use [JSON Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) on the column which you want to modify the view for.

Try this formula on the Title field.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",    
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
            "color": "[$color]",
            "text-align": "center",
            "border": "1px solid [$color]",
            "cursor": "pointer",
            "text-decoration": "none" 
    }
}
```

In `[$color]` - "color" is the internal name of your color column as you have used in your formula.